# How do I pass parameters from view to controlller?

Tags: model-view-controller, view, controller

I am trying to code a little website to book meeting rooms.
I am done adding rooms with no problems. 
But now, I'd like to edit them (like renaming etc.)

---

RoomController
In my controller, I have the action EditerUneRoom which receive a Room object (id,name,number of person).
But it's always null

```
using RoomBooking.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace RoomBooking.Controllers
{
    public class RoomController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Room
        public ActionResult Manage()
        {
            List<Room> listRoom = new List<Room>();

            using (var context = new RoomBookingEntities())
            {
                listRoom = context.Room.ToList();
            }
            return View(listRoom);
        }

        public ActionResult AjouterUneRoom()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult ErrorMsg(string msg)
        {
            ErrorMsg messageErreur = new ErrorMsg();
            messageErreur.text = msg;
            ViewBag.Message = messageErreur;
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult EditerUneRoom(Room editRoom)
        {
            var iden = editRoom.id;
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult AddRoom(string nom, int nbperson)
        {
            Room newRoom = new Room();
            newRoom.nom = nom;
            newRoom.nbPlace = nbperson;

            using (var context = new RoomBookingEntities())
            {
                var roomEntity = context.Room.FirstOrDefault(r => r.nom == nom);
                if(roomEntity == null) 
                {
                    context.Room.Add(newRoom);
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }
                else
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("ErrorMsg", "Room",new { msg = "Cette salle existe déjà !" });
                }

            }

            return RedirectToAction("Manage", "Room");
        }

    }
}
```

---

In the view, I have a list of Room objects displayed with an Actionlink that's supposed to get me to the edit page of the room
View

```
@model List<Room>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Manage";
}

<h2>Manage</h2>

@Html.ActionLink("Ajouter une salle de réunion", "AjouterUneRoom", "Room")

@foreach (var room in Model)
{
    <div>
        <b>Identifiant : </b>
        @room.id
    </div>

    <div>
        <b>Nom : </b>
        @room.nom
    </div>

    <div>
        <b>Nombre de place :</b>
        @room.nbPlace
    </div>

    @Html.ActionLink("Modifier", "EditerUneRoom", "Room", new { wroom = room });
    <br />
}
```

I am working on "EditerUneRoom". I am trying in debug mod to get the parameter "Room editRoom"...
But it's always null.

Any ideas please ?

Answer (score 0):

In the controller, the action `EditerUneRoom`  is waiting for the `editRoom` argument. But it looks like you are passing in `wroom`. Try changing the ActionLink arg name:

```
new { editRoom = room }
```